# Unable to resize main HD after deleting Bootcamp Partition

Tags: macos, hard-drive, bootcamp, partition

[Note:This question is dissimilar to the other ones like this since my Bootcamp partition does not show up on listing the drives in terminal.]

I added my bootcamp partition to parrallels desktop. I removed the VM and opted to keep the files.

Naively, I ran the following commands.

```
diskutil list
diskutil eraseVolume jhfs+ BC1 disk0s3
diskutil eraseVolume fat32 BOOTCAMP disk0s3
```

I then set out to restore my HD using Boot Camp Assistant. It said that there was an error so I ran First Aid on my completely empty Bootcamp partition. After clicking done to continue,the partition VANISHED.

So I was left with 100 gb space missing. Here is my output when I list all the drives:

```
 #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         150.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +150.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            95.7 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 56.0 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                512.4 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Also the following command ,

```
 diskutil cs list
```

..returns the following:

```
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

But on the Apple forums, I saw that they should return output.

Also I was repeatedly getting this error in any attempt I made in restoring my drives.Something to do with my "object map".

```
error: btn: invalid btn_btree.bt_key_count (expected 152418, actual 152419)
```

Is there a way I could perhaps make another partition taking up the remaining space and merge it with my main HD?
Any help would be appreciated!!

Edit: After executing the command

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

....this is what I got back:

```
Started APFS operation
Aligning grow delta to 100,684,705,792 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 250,685,575,168 bytes
Determined the maximum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 250,684,547,072 bytes
Resizing APFS Container designated by APFS Container Reference disk1
The specific APFS Physical Store being resized is disk0s2
Verifying storage system
Using live mode
Performing fsck_apfs -n -x -l -S /dev/disk0s2
Checking the container superblock
Checking the EFI jumpstart record
Checking the space manager
Checking the space manager free queue trees
Checking the object map
Checking volume
Checking the APFS volume superblock
The volume Macintosh HD was formatted by hfs_convert (748.1.47) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.200.129)
```

This did not work, but I can remember reformatting the Boot Camp partition to Mac OS Journaled before I sought to restore the drive.

Edit :

It was something wrong with the B tree node (no idea what that is)!??
So I went into self mode by Cmd-S when restarting.

Then type in the commands:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
```

In my case it pointed out what went wrong and then I typed in YES.

So there where a bunch of y's being printed on the screen.I am assuming it was doing some check of some sort.It ran for well over an hour.I press the power button (dont reccomend doing so,but then again it worked for me) and restarted into Mojave.

And voila I removed the "Free space " using disk utlity and it worked like a charm!

Comment: `sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0`

Comment: @DavidAnderson I executed the command but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Do I have some data that is unaccounted for because I keep getting this error:

Comment: error: btn: invalid btn_btree.bt_key_count (expected 152418, actual 152419)
Object Map Invalid

Comment: The command I posted in my original comment is correct. The problems you are having would appear to have nothing to do with deleting the Boot Camp partition. Your APFS partition may have been already corrupted and you are finding this out just now. I do not know how to fix your present problem.

Comment: Ah my bad.I edited what went wrong into the question